# How can I show breadcrumbs in unfocused tabs when workbench.editor.showTabs is disabled?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode I've disabled `workbench.editor.showTabs`, so tabs are hidden. But one catch is that when I focus a different tab, the breadcrumbs disappear.

Is there a way to configure VSCode so that breadcrumbs are always visible?

[image: focused tab shows breadcrumbs]

[image: unfocused tab not showing breadcrumbs]